# Using ngModel.$formatter with non-input elements

Tags: angularjs

I've been happily manipulating the view using `$parsers` and `$formatters` to transform data in forms. However, when I came to apply the same behaviour to other elements I found it didn't work, as demonstrated here:

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("foo", function ($scope) {
    $scope.n = 1;
  })
  .directive("displayHalf", function () {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function (value) {
          return value*2;
        });

        ngModel.$formatters.push(function (value) {
          return value/2;
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="foo">
    <div>
      Input: <input type="number" display-half ng-model="n">
    </div>
    <div>
      Span: <span display-half ng-model="n">{{n}}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      Button: <button display-half ng-model="n">{{n}}</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      Div: <div display-half ng-model"n">{{n}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I guess I expected a `$formatter` to be applied as data is displayed, even if it couldn't be edited. Was I mistaken? Any way to get this working without writing `{{n / 2}}` all over the place?